# Side by Side bar plot in R- X axis display

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have data like this:

```
data1<-data.frame(order=c(1:3,1:3), gender=c('f','f','f','m','m','m'), count= c(10,20,30,20,25,30))
> data1

  order gender count
1     1      f    10
2     2      f    20
3     3      f    30
4     1      m    20
5     2      m    25
6     3      m    30
```

I need side by side bar plot for females f vs males m over the categories 1,2,3 and counts as in the count column. I am not able to understand how to reshape the data in a form suitable for side by side plots.
This seems to work:

```
ggplot(newtabl, aes(x=order, y=count, fill=gender)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge')
```

But I need to control the labels on the X axis i,e they need to print as '1', '2' and '3' directly underneath the bars. How do I do this?

Comment: X-axis is printing currently 1, 2 an d3. What do you need to change in there?

Comment: Its my fault, I actually have labels 1 through 9, not just 3 - I see it with my dataset which is more complex than the example one. Just gonna have to live wth it

Comment: Can you provide an example dataset where we can actually reproduce the issue that you are facing?